# Compare logistic regression models on same customers

Tags: regression, logistic, model-comparison

I have two logistic models on the same set of customers in telecom. 1. Propensity to convert from fixed line to prepaid line 2. Propensity to convert from fixed line to post-paid line. I have to identify where will the customer convert to i.e., Prepaid/post-paid after comparing the propensity scores.

Now my question: Can I compare the propensity scores of two different models with different independent and dependent variables? (for each customer)